# How to wait for a StartCoroutine() to finish before proceeding

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm making a piece of code that gets a piece of information from MySQL and displays it on the UI. the problem is, the program doesn't wait for the MySQL query to be finished and proceeds straight to displaying the variable (which is empty because the results of the query didn't made it on time)

A rough outline of my code would be:

```
bool notYetDone = true;

StartCoroutine(query(web));

IEnumerator query (WWW web){
    yield return web;
    while(notYetDone == true){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        if(web.error == null){
            //no problems with the query, some code here
            notYetDone = false;
        } else if (web.error != null){
            //some code here for handling errors
        } else {
            Debug.Log("i dont really know why we reached here");
        }
    }
}
```

Something I also noticed is that it seems to change the value of `notYetDone` and ends the loop immediately. Is something wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using web.isDone instead of  notYetDone == true

Comment: directly replacing the while argument with web.isDone seems to produce an infinite loop. but ill try some ways using this. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: what if you use: while(!web.isDone) , so when it finish it will be true and exit the loop.

Comment: what should i put in the loop? im just waiting for the query to be finished

Comment: while(!web.isDone){ //this will loop until your query is finished}if(web.Error == nulll){Debug.log("No errors to display")}else{Debug.Log("Errors on web....")}
I think this could work, can't test it now because I'm at my job, but when I get a chance I could try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
IEnumerator query (WWW web)
{
   //yield return web;
   while(!web.isDone && web.Error == null)
   {
    //this will loop until your query is finished
    //do something while waiting...
      yield return null;
   }
   if(web.Error != null)
     Debug.Log("Errors on web");

}
```

Comment: This is incorrect for two reasons : 
yield return web; 
is enough to wait for the end of the www routine and the while loop is therefore useless, but if coder forgets to yield on web before then it will block the thread until done. to be sure you should either remove it completely or yield null inside

Comment: well... you're right there's no need for the while or you can remove the yield return web, and do something like while(!web.isDone && web.Error == null){ yield return null}if(error!=null){Debug.Log("Errors on web")}, the while loop is just in case he wants to do something while the query is running...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class QueryBehaviour: MonoBehaviour
{
  bool queryFinished = false;
  WWW wwwQuery;

  IEnumerator Query()
  {
    wwwQuery = new WWW("url_to_query");
    yield return wwwQuery;

    queryFinished = true;
    //results or error should be here
  }

  Update()
  {
    if( queryFinished == false )
    {
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      //use wwwQuery here
    }
  }
}
```

Then just call **Query**.

Note: there is no need to busy wait if you call **yield return wwwQuery**. You should busy wait if you don't want to do this, for instance, you want to check a progress download, in which case you should be polling the result of the www class inside the **Update** method defined in **MonoBehaviour**.

Comment: sorry but it still proceeds to the next line of code.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, yes it does go to the next line of code. The operation is async. You need to set a flag after the yield and then you should have your query

Comment: can you explain the flow of this?

Comment: correct me if im wrong but from what i understood, when queryFinished is false, the return command returns it back to the query() and if not, the query is done, am i right?

Comment: Not exactly. Coroutines are run by the Unity runtime async. This means that after you call Query the control goes to the next line in the flow. Unity makes a call to the IEnumerator that you return until it gets a done. This means that the IEnumerator finished and your coroutine finished running. In the update you check if the coroutine finished as Unity doesn't provide another mechanism for this.

Comment: it still doesnt work. however, can you explain to be again how does the return work in the if-else statement?

Comment: Update is called every frame by Unity. This means that you're polling around the queryFinished variable.

Answer (score 1):

Placing the yield keyword before startcoroutine would also have the same effect. In your case:

```
yield StartCoroutine(query(web)); 
//at this point it is guaranteed to be completed
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Comment: But for that you need to already be inside a coroutine. Maybe you were thinking about `IEnumerator Start() { }`

Answer (score 1):

How about using callbacks ?

```
   public void showMessage(string message)
    {
        setMessage(message);
        Debug.Log("start_fadeIn");
        StartCoroutine(coroutine__fadeIn(delegate
        {
            Debug.Log("start_fadeOut");
            StartCoroutine(coroutine__fadeOut(delegate
            {
                Debug.Log("done");
            }));
        }));
    }


    private IEnumerator coroutine__fadeIn(Action completion)
    {
        CanvasGroup canvasGroup = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
        for (float f = 0f; f <= 1; f += 0.01f)
        {
            canvasGroup.alpha = f;
            yield return null;
        }

        completion();
    }

    private IEnumerator coroutine__fadeOut(Action completion)
    {
        CanvasGroup canvasGroup = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
        for (float f = 1f; f >= 0; f -= 0.01f)
        {
            canvasGroup.alpha = f;
            yield return null;
        }

        completion();
    }
```

Warning, this way requires using a .NET version which supports **Action** class.